# gpg-agent "forgetting" password for key, when getting too many requests

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

I'm running Ubuntu (via Regolith) and my gpg key is unlocked when I log in. I'm running multiple decrypt operations in parallel and I noticed, that if I get above 7, `gpg-agent` will "forget" that the key is already unlocked and I get prompted for a pinentry.

```
❯ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.27
libgcrypt 1.10.1
```

I made a minimal working example to demonstrate this in python.

Create a test file to decrypt with: `echo "something" | gpg --encrypt -o test.gpg`. Running `gpg --decrypt test.gpg` in the shell does not prompt for the passphrase.

Using the below script, if the `WORKERNUM` is set below 8 (on my machine, but setting it to 1 I guess should work for any machine) the script is happily decrypting without asking for a passphrase. But if I crank it up to 8 or above I start getting requests for putting in my password, although it seems like not from every process, only some of them. The execution of the processes also obviously start to hang (I'm assuming they are waiting on `gpg-agent`).

```py
import subprocess
import multiprocessing as mp
import time



the_queue = mp.Queue()
WORKERNUM = 7

def worker_main(queue):
    while True:
        msg = queue.get(True)
        print(time.time(), msg)
        out = subprocess.run(["gpg", "--decrypt", "test.gpg"], capture_output=True)
        print(msg, time.time(), out.stdout)


the_pool = mp.Pool(WORKERNUM, worker_main, (the_queue,))

counter = 0
while True:
    counter += 1
    the_queue.put(counter)
    print(the_queue.qsize())
    while the_queue.qsize() > 10:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

I tried passing `--batch` to the decrypt command, but that didn't change anything. I've been looking through the man pages for `gpg` and `gpg-agent` to see if anything is mentioned that could pertain to this, but I couldn't really find anything. I have two questions:

a) why does this happen and
b) is there something I can configure so that instead of having to figure out the max size of the processing pool to avoid this, `gpg` handles this and I don't get a pinentry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After careful monitoring of `journalctl` I found that the *actual* error was `Cannot allocate memory`. Based on [this discussion](https://dev.gnupg.org/T4255), `gpg-agent` can run out of secure memory if multiple thread are trying to access it. Setting `auto-expand-secmem 100` in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` resolves the issue.

```
       --auto-expand-secmem n                                                                                                                                  Allow Libgcrypt to expand its secure memory area as required. The optional
value n is a non-negative integer with a suggested size in bytes of each
additionally allocated secure memory area. The value is rounded up to the next
32 KiB; usual C style prefixes are allowed. For an heavy loaded gpg-agent with
many concurrent connection this option avoids sign or decrypt errors due to out
of secure memory error returns.
```